# AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'chat'

Tags: python, telebot, pymysql

Недавно учу Python, пишу тг бота, не могу понять в чем ошибка, PyCharm отсылает ошибку в файл telebot`а и пишет:

> AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'chat'

```
import telebot
from pymysql.cursors import Cursor
from telebot import types
import pymysql
from config import host, user, password, db_name

token = 'xxxxxx'
bot = telebot.TeleBot(token)
try:
        connection = pymysql.connect(
            host=host,
            port=3306,
            user=user,
            password=password,
            database=db_name,
            cursorclass=pymysql.cursors.DictCursor
        )
        print("successfully connected...")
        print("#" * 20)

        try:
            with connection.cursor() as cursor:
                @bot.message_handler(commands=['start'])
                def start(message):
    
                    markup = types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup(resize_keyboard=True)
                    mess = "Найти фильм по коду "
                    btn1 = types.KeyboardButton(mess)
                    markup.add(btn1)
                    bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, " Привет! Я чат-бот GoodFilms! Чем могу помочь?",
                                     reply_markup=markup)

        finally:
            connection.close()

        @bot.message_handler()
        def echo_message(message):
            if message.text == "Найти фильм по коду ":
                mess1 = "Введите код:"
                bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, mess1)
                bot.register_next_step_handler(mess1, filmcd)


        @bot.message_handler()
        def filmcd(message):
            filmcode = message.text
            print(filmcode)
            bot.register_next_step_handler(bazza, filmcode)



        @bot.message_handler()
        def bazza(message, filmcode):
            try:
                with connection.cursor() as cursor:
                    sql = "SELECT film FROM `codetable` WHERE id = " + filmcode
                    cursor.execute(sql)
                    record = str(cursor.fetchone())
                    record = record.replace('{', ' ').replace('}', ' ').replace("'", " ").replace('film', ' ').replace(
                        ':', ' ')
    
                with connection.cursor() as cursor:
                    irl = "SELECT 'irl' FROM `codetable` WHERE id = " + filmcode
                    cursor.execute(irl)
                    rec1 = str(cursor.fetchone())
                    rec1 = rec1.replace("{", " ").replace("}", " ").replace("irl", 'Ссылка').replace("'", " ")
                result = "Это фильм:" + record + "\n" + " Смотри в тг GOODFILMS прямо сейчас! " + "\n" + rec1
                bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, text=result)
            finally:
                connection.close() 

except:
    print(mes1)

bot.polling(none_stop=True)
```

'''

Полный трейсбек:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\user\Desktop\ServerPy\bot1.py", line 75, in <module>
    bot.polling(none_stop=True)
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\telebot\__init__.py", line 1043, in polling
    self.__threaded_polling(non_stop=non_stop, interval=interval, timeout=timeout, long_polling_timeout=long_polling_timeout,
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\telebot\__init__.py", line 1118, in __threaded_polling
    raise e
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\telebot\__init__.py", line 1074, in __threaded_polling
    self.worker_pool.raise_exceptions()
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\telebot\util.py", line 147, in raise_exceptions
    raise self.exception_info
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\telebot\util.py", line 90, in run
    task(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\telebot\__init__.py", line 6770, in _run_middlewares_and_handler
    result = handler['function'](message)
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\user\Desktop\ServerPy\bot1.py", line 41, in echo_message
    bot.register_next_step_handler(mess1, filmcd)
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\telebot\__init__.py", line 5310, in register_next_step_handler
    chat_id = message.chat.id
              ^^^^^^^^^^^^
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'chat'
```

Comment: Во-первых, почитай про трейсбэки, что это вообще такое. Во-вторых, интерпретатор просто хочет тебе сказать буквально то что сказал: у типа str нету аттрибута chat. Ты его где-то ошибочно поставил. Проверь код на опечатки.

Comment: Вставь полный текст ошибки с трейсбэком и прочим. А также покажи, на какую строку он показывает.

Comment: Ку, кинул трейсбек, чекни, заранее спасибо)

Comment: Вот ссылка https://qaa-engineer.ru/oshibka-attributeerror-str-object-has-no-attribute-chat-chto-delat-telebot-python/ проверь код на описанное там.